# How do I get a Salesforce API field name case sensitive in Apex?

Tags: apex

I am trying to get an API field; the name is case sensitive but here I am getting `Test__c` as a `test__c`. Can you please provide me a proper solution?

My code:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType sobjSchema = schemaMap.get(objtype);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = sobjSchema.getDescribe().fields.getMap();
List<fieldMetaData> fmdList = new List<fieldMetaData>();
for (String fieldName: fieldMap.keySet()) {  
    String fieldlabel;
    String fieldType;
    //It provides to get the object fields label.
    fieldlabel = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getLabel();

    Schema.DisplayType FldType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();
    fieldType = string.valueOf(FldType);
    system.debug('fieldlabel>>>>>'+fieldlabel);
     system.debug('fieldAPI****>>>>>'+fieldName);

    fieldMetaData fmd = new fieldMetaData();
    fmd.fieldLabel = fieldlabel;
    fmd.fieldapi = fieldName;
    fmd.fieldType = fieldType;
    fmdList.add(fmd);
}
return fmdList;
```

Answer (score 5):

The field map's keys are always lowercase and treated case-insensitively. To the the properly-cased value, use the value from the DescribeFieldResult instead. I'd recommend using the values, not the keys, from this map, to make your life easier:

```
for (SOobjectField field: fieldMap.values()) {  
  DescribeFieldresult fieldDesc = field.getDescribe();
  String fieldName = fieldDesc.getName(),
    fieldLabel = fieldDesc.getLabel();
  Schema.DisplayType fieldType = fieldDesc.getType();
  // Do more stuff here
```